# Firebase real time database compound query combining text and date

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make a compound query (combining two children). What I want to do is fetch objects that are older than 5 minutes AND also are of a type.

So I've combined the children `type` and `date` into a new child called `type_date` and I do my query like this:

```
const now = Date.now();
const fiveMinutesMs = 5*60*1000;
const fiveMinutesAgo = now - fiveMinutesMs;

const fiveMinutesAgoQuery = "type_" + fiveMinutesAgo;

ref.orderByChild('type_date').endAt(fiveMinutesAgoQuery).once('value');
```

Only thing is that it doesn't work. It's giving me results of objects which doesn't even have the `type_date` child.

Comment: What is your exact data model? What do you store in the `type_date` field?

Comment: I store type combined with date in ms for instance "type_1551172088724"

Comment: Could you provide your data sample?

Answer (score 0):

Try startAt instead of endAt. I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Oops I was too quick.... it works only if I'm only filtering on the date string but not together with the prepended type which I want...

So this works:

```
const fiveMinutesAgoIso = new Date(fiveMinutesAgo).toISOString();
const fiveMinutesAgoQuery = String(fiveMinutesAgoIso);
```

But not:

```
const fiveMinutesAgoIso = new Date(fiveMinutesAgo).toISOString();
const fiveMinutesAgoQuery = "type_" + fiveMinutesAgoIso;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a Compound queries as doc says :

```
const fiveMinutesAgoIso = new Date(fiveMinutesAgo).toISOString();

ref.where("type", "==", TYPE_YOU_WANT).orderByChild('type').endAt(fiveMinutesAgoQuery).once('value');
```